# Android: Can't load bitmap image more than one time

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm reading lots of post about bitmap on android and couldn't find any explanation that fits with my code.
I'm saving image from camera inside sdcard, than when i try to show all image i get the error bellow.

```
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:650)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:389)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at br.com.rigolas.financial.activity.InsertItem.getBitmap(InsertItem.java:415)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at br.com.rigolas.financial.activity.InsertItem.showAttachment(InsertItem.java:194)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at br.com.rigolas.financial.activity.InsertItem.populateFields(InsertItem.java:184)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at br.com.rigolas.financial.activity.InsertItem.onResume(InsertItem.java:144)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1188)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5280)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2606)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2644)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2130)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
06-09 20:38:03.732: E/AndroidRuntime(3657):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code:

```
showAttachment(atts);
```

where atts is an Array os paths

```
private void showAttachment(List<Attachment> atts) {

    for(Attachment att : atts){
        insertPhoto(getBitmap(att.getPath()));
    }

}

public Bitmap getBitmap(String path){

    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);

    return bitmap;

}

public void insertPhoto(Bitmap btmp){
    final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.photo_item, mContainerView, false);


    newView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),btmp));
    ImageView delete = (ImageView) newView.findViewById(R.id.photo_expense_discart);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //mContainerView.removeView(newView);
            Intent imageDetil = new Intent(InsertItem.this,ImageDetailActivity.class);
            InsertItem.this.startActivity(imageDetil);
        }
    });

    mContainerView.addView(newView, 0);
}
```

And my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="130dp"
android:layout_height="130dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:alpha="80"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_expense_discart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_content_discard_w" />
</LinearLayout>
```

if I do that with one image works fine, but when I try to show more than one, i get the error, does anyone know how can I solve that?thanks

Comment: This post should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/823966/1852466

Answer (score 0):

Check at this piece of the code you provided:

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(String path){

    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);

    return bitmap;

}
```

In the line  `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);`, you are probably tryng to decode a file too big, resulting in an outofmemory exception.